# Automation Anywhere cannot toggle between 2 tabs with same name

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I am using Automation Anywhere version 10.5, I use a particular IE window named "ABC Viewer" and do certain object cloning operations on the page, while keeping this page open, I have a requirement to open open another duplicate page and perform certain operations on that page , close the new page and come back to the original page.

Sounds simple, but Automation anywhere cannot distinguish between the 2 pages when they are open as they have same Page Title, and it only picks the first page in object cloning.

How can this issue be resolved or is it a short coming of AA

Answer (score 2):

I had the same experience, and I used a Current window in object cloning to solve it.
Also, you can try to change the window name using the browser's console, like document.title = 'ABC'.